# Dispatching a list of commands

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to create a configuration file with a list of commands that my program will run on a event. It is a string list and the method to get it is `getConfig().getStringList()`. I am trying to put this inside `Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(command_goes_here);` How could I get the list of strings (commands) and execute them all?

Comment: Show what you've tried (if anything?).

Comment: Ah no, I haven't tried anything. Not sure how to execute a whole list of things at all. I think I could put it into an array and do so though.

Comment: You can't play Bukkit without a knowledge of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines.

```
@EventHandler
public void onEvent(SomeEvent e) {
    for(String command : thePlugin.getConfig().getStringList(configPath)) {
        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(someCommandSender, command)  
    }
}
```

I can't be very specific, as your question isn't either.