# How to use normal Minecraft commands in a Minecraft Plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I want to program a Minecraft plugin and I want to use commands that are standard in Minecraft like the /worldboarder set command.

Specifically, I would like to program a plugin that set the worldboarder on 1000 blocks, and every hour it gets 50 blocks smaller. Is it possible to use the standard command in my plugin in a loop? Like the command /worldboarder set 1000 and how I use them in my plugin.

I would like to do something like this:

```java
int distance = 1000;
while(distance > 100) {
    wait(3600000);
    // "/worldboarder set " + distance -50; // here how to run cmd ?
}
```

Comment: Hi, where are you stuck exactly ? Did you already write a plugin or something ? I understand what you want to do, but I want to know what is your begin, I will not make the plugin from 0, but I can give you the scheduler and all of what is in

Comment: In principle, I am still at zero. I have programmed a /heal command for practice to gain a little experience. So the plugin can also be activated in MC so far and now I want to include a command that controls the worldboarder, so to speak.
My approach would be approximately so:                                                              
'int distance = 1000;
while(distance > 100) {
wait(3600000);
"/worldboarder set " + distance -50;     //How do I add the /worldboarder set command in my code?'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispatching a list of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235479/dispatching-a-list-of-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't use `wait` function in the server, this will freeze the entiere server which is a big issue. You have to use `Scheduler` (see later).

Then, to run a simple comment, you have to use this:

```
Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "mycmd arg1 arg2");
```

So, you have to do something like that :

```java
private int border = 1000; // actual border value
private BukkitTask task; // bukkit task to cancel it

@Override
public void onEnable() {
   task = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, () -> { // start lambda expression
      Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "worldboarder set " + border); // run cmd
      if(border == 100) { // no longer need to change world border.
         task.cancel(); // cancel actual task to never run it again
         return;
      }
      border -= 50; // reduce border amount for next time
   }, 20, 60 * 60 * 20);
}
```

Few additionnal informations :

- The `runTaskTimer` method accept few arguments : the plugin, the runnable scheduler, the time before start (in tick) and the time between each call (in tick)
- 20 ticks = 1 second. Such as you want each hour: 60 * 60 = seconds per hour, so 60 * 60 * 20 = tick per hour
- The time before start is 20 (so 1s) because spigot start plugin BEFORE fully load world. So it will not find worlds. And it will start to run scheduler after full server start (so after world). 1s is just to be sure, such as it doesn't change anything to gameplay to wait 1s at startup.
- Don't need "/" in command. The `/` is the default character to say it's a command. Such as here we clearly say it's a command, we don't have to use it. [Example](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/165106/)

---

Documentation :

- [Lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In newer bukkit versions, you can use the bukkit.WorldBorder object (https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/WorldBorder.html)

You can modify the worldborder of a world by fisrt getting the world then getting its WorldBorder object

```java
World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world"); // Most of the time the default world is named "world"
WorldBorder border = world.getWorldBorder();
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the worldborder

```java
border.setSize(border.getSize() - 50); // Reduce the size of the border by 50 instantly
```

Hope this will be usefull if someone finds this post